# CUDA reduction to find the maximum of an array

Tags: c, arrays, cuda, parallel-processing

I am doing the Udacity course on parallel programming (homework 3) and can not figure out why I can't get the maximum in the array using parallel reduction (Udacity forums yet to provide solution). I am pretty certain that I have set up the arrays properly and that the algorithm is correct. I suspect that I have a problem with memory management (accessing out of bounds, incorrect array sizes, copying to and from). Please help! I am running this in the Udacity environment, not locally. Below is the code that I am currently using. For some reason when I change the `fmaxf`'s to `fminf`'s it does find the minimum.

```
#include "reference_calc.cpp"
#include "utils.h"
#include "math.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>

__global__ void reduce_max_kernel(float *d_out, const float *d_logLum, int size) {

    // Reduce log Lum with Max Operator
    int myId = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    int tid  = threadIdx.x;

    extern __shared__ float temp[];

    if (myId < size) {
        temp[tid] = d_logLum[myId];
    }
    else {
        temp[tid] = d_logLum[tid];
    }

    for (unsigned int s = blockDim.x / 2; s > 0; s >>= 1) {
        if (tid < s) {
            if (myId < size) {
                temp[tid] = fmaxf(d_logLum[myId + s], d_logLum[myId]);
            } else {
                temp[tid] = d_logLum[tid];
            }
        }
        __syncthreads(); 
    }

    if (tid == 0) {
        d_out[blockIdx.x] = temp[0];
    }
}

__global__ void reduce_max_kernel2(float *d_out, float *d_in) {

    // Reduce log Lum with Max Operator
    int myId = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    int tid  = threadIdx.x;

    for (unsigned int s = blockDim.x >> 1; s > 0; s >>= 1) {
        if (tid < s) {
            d_in[myId] = fmaxf(d_in[myId + s], d_in[myId]);
        }
        __syncthreads();   
    }

    if (tid == 0) {
        d_out[0] = d_in[0];
    }

}


void your_histogram_and_prefixsum(const float* const d_logLuminance,
                                  unsigned int* const d_cdf,
                                  float &min_logLum,
                                  float &max_logLum,
                                  const size_t numRows,
                                  const size_t numCols,
                                  const size_t numBins)
{
  //TODO
  /*Here are the steps you need to implement
    1) find the minimum and maximum value in the input logLuminance channel
       store in min_logLum and max_logLum
    2) subtract them to find the range
    3) generate a histogram of all the values in the logLuminance channel using
       the formula: bin = (lum[i] - lumMin) / lumRange * numBins
    4) Perform an exclusive scan (prefix sum) on the histogram to get
       the cumulative distribution of luminance values (this should go in the
       incoming d_cdf pointer which already has been allocated for you)       */
    //int size = 1 << 18;
    int points = numRows * numCols;
    int logPoints = ceil(log(points)/log(2));
    int sizePow = logPoints;
    int size = pow(2, sizePow);
    int numThreads = 1024;
    int numBlocks = size / numThreads;

    float *d_out;
    float *d_max_out;

    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void **) &d_out, numBlocks * sizeof(float)));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void **) &d_max_out, sizeof(float)));

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    reduce_max_kernel<<<numBlocks, numThreads, sizeof(float)*numThreads>>>(d_out, d_logLuminance, points);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    reduce_max_kernel2<<<1, numBlocks>>>(d_max_out, d_out);

    float h_out_max;
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(&h_out_max, d_max_out, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    printf("%f\n", h_out_max);

    checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(d_max_out));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(d_out));

}
```

Comment: If you want help debugging your code, we need to see the shortest *complete* example someone else could compile and run.

Comment: In your `reduce_max_kernel` it's generally recommended to use a `__syncthreads()` after populating or modifying shared memory.  You have it in your reduce for-loop, but you don't seem to have one after the initial loading of shared memory (prior to the for-loop).  Some threads could race ahead and enter the for-loop before others have had an opportunity to do the initial load of shared memory.  Also, the purpose of using shared memory is to actually make use of it in your reduce-for-loop.  Right now your for-loop is loading values from global, not shared memory.  That is broken.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to reproduce the `reduce2` reduction kernel of the CUDA SDK reduction sample. Robert Crovella has already spot two mistakes that you have made in your code. Besides them, I think you are also mistakenly initializing the shared memory.

Below, please find a complete working example constructed around your attempt. I have left the wrong instructions of your approach.

```
#include <thrust\device_vector.h>

#define BLOCKSIZE 256

/********************/
/* CUDA ERROR CHECK */
/********************/
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        if (abort) { getchar(); exit(code); }
    }
}

/*******************************************************/
/* CALCULATING THE NEXT POWER OF 2 OF A CERTAIN NUMBER */
/*******************************************************/
unsigned int nextPow2(unsigned int x)
{
    --x;
    x |= x >> 1;
    x |= x >> 2;
    x |= x >> 4;
    x |= x >> 8;
    x |= x >> 16;
    return ++x;
}

__global__ void reduce_max_kernel(float *d_out, const float *d_logLum, int size) {

    int tid         = threadIdx.x;                              // Local thread index
    int myId        = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;    // Global thread index

    extern __shared__ float temp[];

    // --- Loading data to shared memory. All the threads contribute to loading the data to shared memory.
    temp[tid] = (myId < size) ? d_logLum[myId] : -FLT_MAX;

    // --- Your solution
    // if (myId < size) { temp[tid] = d_logLum[myId]; } else { temp[tid] = d_logLum[tid]; }

    // --- Before going further, we have to make sure that all the shared memory loads have been completed
    __syncthreads();

    // --- Reduction in shared memory. Only half of the threads contribute to reduction.
    for (unsigned int s=blockDim.x/2; s>0; s>>=1)
    {
        if (tid < s) { temp[tid] = fmaxf(temp[tid], temp[tid + s]); }
        // --- At the end of each iteration loop, we have to make sure that all memory operations have been completed
        __syncthreads();
    }

    // --- Your solution
    //for (unsigned int s = blockDim.x / 2; s > 0; s >>= 1) {
    //    if (tid < s) { if (myId < size) { temp[tid] = fmaxf(d_logLum[myId + s], d_logLum[myId]); } else { temp[tid] = d_logLum[tid]; } }
    //    __syncthreads(); 
    //}

    if (tid == 0) {
        d_out[blockIdx.x] = temp[0];
    }
}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main()
{
    const int N = 10;

    thrust::device_vector<float> d_vec(N,3.f); d_vec[4] = 4.f;

    int NumThreads  = (N < BLOCKSIZE) ? nextPow2(N) : BLOCKSIZE;
    int NumBlocks   = (N + NumThreads - 1) / NumThreads;

    // when there is only one warp per block, we need to allocate two warps
    // worth of shared memory so that we don't index shared memory out of bounds
    int smemSize = (NumThreads <= 32) ? 2 * NumThreads * sizeof(int) : NumThreads * sizeof(int);

    // --- reduce2
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_vec_block(NumBlocks);
    reduce_max_kernel<<<NumBlocks, NumThreads, smemSize>>>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_vec_block.data()), thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_vec.data()), N);

    // --- The last part of the reduction, which would be expensive to perform on the device, is executed on the host
    thrust::host_vector<float> h_vec_block(d_vec_block);
    float result_reduce0 = -FLT_MAX;
    for (int i=0; i<NumBlocks; i++) result_reduce0 = fmax(h_vec_block[i], result_reduce0);
    printf("Result = %f\n",result_reduce0);

}
```